# Address UIWebView from different .m-file than ViewController.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm checking out a new type of menu (https://github.com/szrambo/fancymenu) and I would like it to work on a UIWebView as well. It shows and hides perfectly on the screen, but when I add a WebView, it does get shown on longpress, but it only hides when I tap the screen - not on the WebView.

I can't seem to address my WebView from a different .m-file than the ViewController.m-file. My problem is that when I try to write

```
[myWebView addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
```

into FAFancyMenuView.m instead of the FAViewController.m, I get the error that myWebView is an unknown receiver...

Answer (score 0):

Gestures on UIWebViews are detected from the UIWebView itself, so the menu cannot detect the UITouches on the UIWebView. What you can do is to place a transparent UIview over the UIWebView and insert it in a container UIview, so gestures can be detected.
Here a simple code on how to do it:

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:yourframe];
UIView *overView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:container.bounds];
container.backgroundColor = overView .backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[container addSubView: yourWebView];
[container addSubView: overView];
[overView addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
```